# Thin server logs the same request several times

Tags: ruby, logging, heroku, sinatra, thin

I'm using thin web server, to serve a Ruby/Sinatra application. The thing that got my attention is that when I run:

```
RACK_ENV=production rackup
```

Every request is logged like 5 times, and with different timestamps.

```
vagrant@lucid32:/app$ RACK_ENV=production rackup
** Building /assets/application.js...
** Building /assets/screen.css...
>> Thin web server (v1.4.1 codename Chromeo)
>> Maximum connections set to 1024
>> Listening on 0.0.0.0:9292, CTRL+C to stop
10.0.2.2 - - [12/Aug/2012 03:54:56] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 4 0.0024
10.0.2.2 - - [12/Aug/2012 03:54:56] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 4 0.0034
10.0.2.2 - - [12/Aug/2012 03:54:56] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 4 0.0044
10.0.2.2 - - [12/Aug/2012 03:54:56] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 4 0.0054
10.0.2.2 - - [12/Aug/2012 03:54:56] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 4 0.0065
10.0.2.2 - - [12/Aug/2012 03:54:56] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 4 0.0076
10.0.2.2 - - [12/Aug/2012 03:54:56] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 4 0.0094
10.0.2.2 - - [12/Aug/2012 03:54:56] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 - 0.0102
```

That leaves me to believe that somehow the request is made several times. Or is just logging it many times?

When I run just

```
rackup
```

And try the same request. This is what I get instead.

```
vagrant@lucid32:/app$ rackup
>> Thin web server (v1.4.1 codename Chromeo)
>> Maximum connections set to 1024
>> Listening on 0.0.0.0:9292, CTRL+C to stop
10.0.2.2 - - [12/Aug/2012 03:56:42] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 - 0.1228
```

The differences are basically the "-" after the status code, like the final log line in the production server. But I don't really know what that means.

I would like to know if somehow in production the request is processed many times.
I'm using Sinatra like this, with this route.

```
class Project::Base < Sinatra::Application
  ..configs here
end

class Project::Routes::Home < Project::Base
  get '/'
    "something"
  end
end
```

config.ru

```
RACK_ENV = ENV["RACK_ENV"] ||= "development" unless defined? RACK_ENV
require 'sprockets'
map '/assets' do
  environment = Sprockets::Environment.new
  environment.append_path 'app/assets/javascripts'
  environment.append_path 'app/assets/stylesheets'

  run environment
end
require File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/config/boot.rb'
use Rack::Deflater
run GRBTV::Main
```

./config/boot.rb

```
require 'rubygems'
gem 'psych'

# Require default environment config
require File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), 'env')

# Bundler setup check 
require 'bundler'
begin
  Bundler.setup
rescue Bundler::BundlerError => e
  $stderr.puts e.message
  $stderr.puts "Run 'bundle install' to install missing gems"
  exit e.status_code
end


# Sinatra
require 'sinatra/base'
require 'sinatra/flash'
require 'json'

RACK_ENV = ENV['RACK_ENV'] ||= 'development' unless defined? RACK_ENV
ROOT_DIR = File.dirname(__FILE__).gsub(/config/,'')  unless defined? ROOT_DIR

# Path helper methods 
# root_path("config", "settings.yml")
def root_path(*args)
  File.join(ROOT_DIR, *args)
end

# relative_from_root_path("~/projects/project_name/config/settings.yml") #=> "config/settings.yml"
def relative_from_root_path(path)
  Pathname.new(path).relative_path_from(Pathname.new(ROOT_DIR)).to_s
end

# public_path("images") #=> "public/images"
def public_path(*args)
  root_path('public', *args)
end

# Module containers for autoloaded helpers and routes
module GRBTV
  module Helpers
  end
  module Routes
  end
end

# Attempts to require all dependencies with bundler, if this fails, bundle and then try again
require 'bundler'
Bundler.setup(:default)
Bundler.require(:default)

# Dependencies contains all required gems and core configuration
require root_path('config', 'dependencies.rb')

def app() GRBTV::Main end
```

./config/dependencies.rb

```
require File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), './loader')

initializers = []
# Requires initializers
Loader.load_files('config/initializers/*.rb') do |file|
  require file
  begin
    # Save Initializer module in the initializers array
    file_class = File.basename(file, '.rb').camelize
    initializers << "#{file_class}Initializer".constantize
  rescue NameError
  end
end

require 'yaml'
YAML::ENGINE.yamler = 'psych'

# Load app components
['lib/*.rb', 'app/uploaders/*.rb', 'app/models/*.rb'].each do |glob|
  Loader.load_files(glob)
end


# Basic Sinatra::Application settingss
class GRBTV::Base < Sinatra::Application
  def options() settings end

  set :root, root_path
  set :views, root_path('app', 'views')
  set :public_folder, root_path('public')
  set :environment, RACK_ENV.to_sym if defined? RACK_ENV
    set :protection, :except => :frame_options

  use Rack::MethodOverride
  enable :sessions
  register Sinatra::NamedRoutes
  register MongoMapper
  helpers Sinatra::FieldBuilder
  helpers Sinatra::Warden::Helpers

  # Require all helpers
  Loader.load_files("app/helpers/**/*.rb") do |file|
    relative_path = relative_from_root_path(file).gsub(/\.rb$/, '').gsub('app/helpers/', '')
    module_name = "GRBTV::Helpers::#{relative_path.camelize}"
    Loader.define_namespaces(module_name)
    require file
    helpers module_name.constantize
  end


  # Sets the default layout for every route
  before do
    @default_layout = :'layout'
  end

  before '/assets/*' do
    headers['Cache-Control'] = 'public, max-age=86400'
  end
end

# Load mailers
Loader.load_files('app/mailers/*.rb')


class GRBTV::Main < GRBTV::Base
  # Requiring routes after extending path helpers
  Loader.load_files("app/routes/**/*.rb") do |file|
    relative_path= relative_from_root_path(file).gsub(/\.rb$/, '').gsub('app/routes/', '')
    module_name = "GRBTV::Routes::#{relative_path.camelize}"
    Loader.define_namespaces(module_name)
    require file
    use module_name.constantize
  end
end

# Load all initializers after setup is done
initializers.each do |initializer|
  GRBTV::Base.register initializer
end
```

Comment: The format is the [Apache common log format](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/logs.html#common), with the addition of the total time for the request at the end. It looks like you have multiple instances of the `Rack::CommonLogger` middleware in your production rack stack (which would explain the increasing time values). How do you configure your app for production (in both your app files and your `config.ru` file)?

Comment: Also (this is probably not related to your logging problem – but might be) [you shouldn’t really subclass `Sinatra::Application`](https://github.com/sinatra/sinatra/blob/v1.3.2/lib/sinatra/base.rb#L1573-1579). Use [`Sinatra::Base` instead](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro.html#Sinatra::Base%20-%20Middleware,%20Libraries,%20and%20Modular%20Apps).

Comment: matt, I just added the info of my config.ru, /config/boot.rb, and /config/dependencies.rb. Those are my main startup files, and the ones with all the configurations. I don't really know how to just have one Rack::CommonLogger. And, as you pointed out in the link, I'm subclassing from SinatraApplication because I do want all the helpers, and stuff on the rest of my controllers. Does that makes sense? Thankyou!

Answer (score 0):

This is a Sinatra/Thin bug and should be fixed in Sinatra 1.3.3 (released yesterday).